# Running command in a docker

Tags: docker, elastic-stack

I have an ELK stack docker cloned from here:

https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk

The docker contains the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:latest
  command: elasticsearch -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
logstash:
  image: logstash:latest
  command: logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
  volumes:
    - ./logstash/config:/etc/logstash/conf.d
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  links:
    - elasticsearch
kibana:
  build: kibana/
  volumes:
    - ./kibana/config/:/opt/kibana/config/
  ports:
    - "5601:5601"
  links:
    - elasticsearch
```

Now I can start the docker daemon using `docker-compose up -d` command - but now I want to import something using logstash, so I need to use `logstash` command - how can I do this? Being in the docker location I get an error that the command cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still the case, but on their Dockerfile, someone posted the following - https://hub.docker.com/_/logstash/

''It looks like this is impossible to use from docker-compose? As it doesn't support passing arguments. Is there another way I can tell logstash where the config file is, perhaps an environment variable?''